# RESTful API Design: PUT or POST for creating many-to-many relationships?

Tags: api, rest, http

For designing and creating a RESTful API the following question occurs:

The API supports GET (for queries), POST (for creating), PUT (for updates) and DELETE (for deleting).

Lets assume in the database we have an **article** and a **shop** both already existing.

Now we need a rest call to link the article instance to the shop instance. Which of the following solutions is the best / most clean REST design:

1. /shop/id/article/id/ --> with POST
2. /shop/id/article/id/ --> with PUT
3. /shoparticlerelation/ --> with POST (object with ids in body)
4. /shoparticlerelation/ --> with PUT (object with ids in body)

If there is no clear answer or all solutions are equally good this may also be a valid answer if there is a clear argumentation why.

Comment: What is the relation between articles and shops in plain english?

Comment: Multiple shops and multiple articles - every article may be sold in every shop but only if it is connected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume in this situation you already have a collection of `shop`s and a collection of `article`s, and you just wish to link two together.

One option is to expose a more db like 'resource' that presents this link, and have operations like

```
POST /shopArticleLinks HTTP/1.1

{ "shop"  : xxx,
  "article: YYY
}
```

I would personally look to expose it as a property of the shops and/or articles in a more natural manor, like

```
PUT /shop/<ID> HTTP/1.1

{ /* existing details */
  "articles": [ /* list of articles */ ]
}
```

I've used JSON there, but of course use what ever format you want to use. I've also stuck with using PUT as you stated, but keep in mind that with PUT you should send a full replacement for the new modified version, PATCH can be used to send partial updates, but then you need to consider how you want do that, may something like

```
PATCH /shops/<ID>/articleLinks HTTP/1.1

{ "add"   : [],
  "remove : []
}
```

Don't forget that server side you can look at what `articles` are being refereed to and ensure they have a proper back pointer.

---

<sub>**Additional thoughts**</sub>

Regarding the second method, where you expose the link as a property of the `shop` and/or `article` resources. Keep in mind that it is perfectly acceptable (and in this case rather appropriate) that when you update the links in a given `shop` that the links in the corresponding `articles` are also updated.

Comment: It sounds viable, but creating a new resource just to link 2 others is a step on the way to what design patterns call *"class explosion"*

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely not the the option I would go with. It does mirror the way it would most likely be stored in the DB, but that's ignoring the 'REpresentational' part of REST :P

Answer (score 1):

> `/shop/id/article/id/`

You cannot use this because at the moment you want to link them, this endpoint doesn't (or at least shouldn't) yet exist. It is the action of linking them together that should define this endpoint.

> `/shoparticlerelation/`

You should not use this because a `shoparticlerelation` is not a resource / entity. Usually with rest, every named url segment represents a resource that can be CRUD-ed. `/shops` is a good example and so is `/articles` but this one isn't.

---

I suggest the following:

Define the following endpoints

`/shops` for POSTing new shops
`/shops/id` for operating on a single shop
`/articles` for POSTing new articles
`/articles/id` for operating on a single article

Then to link them together you can do a so called PATCH request, to update a shop's articles, or an article's shops:

```
PATCH /shops/1 HTTP/1.1

{
    "attribute": "articles",
    "operation": "add",
    "value": "8" // the article id
}
```

and

```
PATCH /articles/9 HTTP/1.1

{
    "attribute": "shops",
    "operation": "add",
    "value": "1" // the shop id
}
```

Based on your comments I made the assumption that an Article model has a list of Shops as attribute, and vice-versa, making this approach valid.

A PATCH request is used to modify an existing resource by specifying how and what to update. This is different from a PUT because a PUT replaces the entire resource with values from the request, however PATCH is only used to modify (not replace) a resource.

Comment: I'd +1 for you suggesting PATCH, but it's cancelled out by using two requests for the one action.

Comment: @thecoshman I suggested 2 ways to link them here with the 2 patch requests. I would probably link them both ways in the same request, regardless of via which resource you're patching.

Comment: Ah I see, basically what I suggested, just not as explicitly.

Comment: "You cannot use this because at the moment you want to link them, this endpoint doesn't (or at least shouldn't) yet exist." - isn't that a matter of taste and how you decide to define when a resource relation exists or not? To me it seems valid that if *shopid* and *articleid* themselves exist, /shops/shopid/articles/articleid could also always exist. A GET on this resource could by default return {linked: false}. To add or remove an article from a shop, PUT could be used to update the *linked* attribute.

Comment: "a shoparticlerelation is not a resource / entity" - disagree. The relationship can be considered a resource from REST standpoint. You can list these resources, create/update/delete them. Right now, this relationship has only two IDs in it's body (`shop_id`, `article_id`). In the future, you may add more attributes, like `created_at` (when the relationship was created),`expires_at`, etc.