# What would be the appropriate REST endpoint for doing a bulk assignment in a many-to-many relationships

Tags: rest, api, http

Suppose I have 4 tables: **Courses**, **Tutorials**, **Quizzes**, and **Tutorials-Quizzes**.

The relationships are as followed:

- **Courses** and **Tutorials** is one-to-many: each course has many tutorials and each tutorial belongs to one course.
- **Courses** and **Quizzes** is one-to-many: each course has have many quizzes and each quiz belongs to one course.
- **Tutorials** and **Quizzes** is many-to-many: each tutorial can be assigned to many quizzes and each quiz can be assigned to many tutorials.
- **Tutorial-Quizzes** acts as bridge between these two. Each record holds two fields which are the IDs of the tutorial and quiz.

Now, for a particular course, I can assign multiple tutorials to mutiple quizzes (in bulk) with one operation. When a tutorial is assigned with a quiz, a new record is added in the **Tutorials-Quizzes** table.

What would be the appropriate method and resource name for doing this bulk assignment?

```
PATCH /courses/id/tutorials/quizzes
PATCH /courses/id/quizzes/tutorials
PATCH /courses/id/tutorials-quizzes
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843920/restful-api-design-put-or-post-for-creating-many-to-many-relationships) relates sort of to what I am asking but mines is slightly different as I am assigning multiples items in two different collections with in operation.

Comment: /courses/id/assignTutorialsToQuizzes .  Note the plural verbiage.

Comment: Looks like tutorials and quizzes already have many-to-many relationship via courses. Are you sure you want a separate many-to-many relationship via another table?

Comment: @Rei Yes because I have fields that apply only to the bridge table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either POST  or Patch

**Post:**
POST method is typically used to add an element when used on list resource but you can also support several actions for this method.

```
POST /batch
[
  { method: 'POST', path: '/items', body: { title: 'foo' } },
  { method: 'DELETE', path: '/items/bar' }
]



POST/courses/id/tutorials/quizzes
```

**Patch:**
In the case, it's not necessary to define your format to describe the update.
Using a PATCH method is also suitable since corresponding requests correspond to a partial update. According to RFC5789 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789)

```
PATCH /items
[ { id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' } ]


PATCH /courses/id/tutorials/quizzes
```

Example : Google Drive API

POST https://www.googleapis.com/batch

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.20.0 (gzip)
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=END_OF_PART
Content-Length: 963

--END_OF_PART
Content-Length: 337
Content-Type: application/http
content-id: 1
content-transfer-encoding: binary


POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id
Authorization: Bearer authorization_token
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8


{
  "emailAddress":"example@appsrocks.com",
  "role":"writer",
  "type":"user"
}
--END_OF_PART
Content-Length: 353
Content-Type: application/http
content-id: 2
content-transfer-encoding: binary


POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions?fields=id&sendNotificationEmail=false
Authorization: Bearer authorization_token
Content-Length: 58
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8


{
   "domain":"appsrocks.com",
   "role":"reader",
   "type":"domain"
}
--END_OF_PART--
```

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch

https://saw.saas.hp.com/help/en/full/Content/8000_DeveloperGuide/ApiRESTBulkUpdate.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_flat.htm

**Resource Naming Guidline:**

http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.